# How to reopen the question which is on Hold

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

[Export data from SQL server to Redis via SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57010430/export-data-from-sql-server-to-redis-via-ssis) is my question. It is a direct question as I am expecting the possibility of connection between *SQL Server* and *Redis* via *SSIS*. I am not sure how other way we can ask this question.

Nevertheless it is mentioned as Broad and put on Hold.

I have few questions related to that:

1. If some one downvotes and put on Hold, will they leave any comment if so where I can see that?
2. How to re-open the question?
3. My assumption is question is marked broad by Subject matter experts and not by any content admins.

Comment: Several users voted to close your question. The close-banner tells you what the general problem with your question, and include links to very useful help center pages with a lot of information on how to write good questions that fit the site's model.

Comment: Regarding to your "how to reopen" question look at: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-do-you-reopen-a-closed-question

Comment: @yivi the banner says the question should be very specific. But what I am trying to understand is the question is already a specific one and I am trying to get a specific answer. how to write /modify such direct questions

Comment: Yes, it says that.

Answer (score 12):

> If some one downvotes and put on Hold, will they leave any comment if so where I can see that?

No, they don't have to. When a question gets put on hold, you'll see by whom.

> How to re-open the question?

By editing it to make it on-topic and answerable, and hoping.

> My assumption is question is marked broad by Subject matter experts and not by any content admins.

So? All users who can vote, are allowed (and encouraged) to do so. There are no "content admins", every user with the appropriate reputation can vote on other users' content. That's the way this site works.

Now you've asked a Meta question. What is your goal? Do you want to play nice and follow the site rules and ask an on-topic, answerable question, or do you just want your problem solved no matter whether it's a good fit for this site?

Your initial question came down to *"How to synchronize two database systems"*, more or less. That is, by definition, too broad a question because there are a million ways to do so.

Your question is not "direct" or "specific" as you claim here. Yes, it mentions two specific database systems, but that still makes the question, *"How to push SQL data to Redis"*, too broad.

So, about your actual question and how to improve it: are you actually looking for an SSIS connector to Redis, and that's it? So you can drag and drop lines between columns of both sides, and make a package that does the data transformation?

You can try to find a connector yourself, as asking for specific tools and libraries is off-topic on Stack Overflow.

So with that option ruled out, how can you make your question not too broad and on-topic? That depends on what options are available to you, what solutions you find appropriate and which not, and none of that is present in your current question.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I am quite new to Stack overflow so tried to validate my assumption.  The Goal is to get the solution for my answer. I tried in most of the official site to see whether there is SSIS connector available. I couldn't find so I asked help in stack overflow that someone might aware of it. Now I get to know from your comment that this is off topic for stack overflow site.

Comment: You've been a member for 3.5 years according to your profile, but see Help Center -> [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam"_.

Comment: The OP was clear that they wanted to use SSIS, so I don't think the 'million ways to do it' bit applies. And if there is no SSIS connector available then it's appropriate to come here for help coding a workaround, surely (though obviously it would have been good if they had demonstrated a bit more research).

Comment: @MandyShaw yes, that is true, but that's implicit, not explicit. Also, you can write a .NET assembly to be executed within an SSIS package, so you could solve it in any way imaginable.

Comment: @CodeCaster Thanks we used stackexchange.redis to achieve this.